# VScode extension clean diagnostic collection on second run

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a `diagnosticCollection` on a vscode extension following this 
[sample:](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/diagnostic-related-information-sample/src/extension.ts)

It works but if I run the same command twice on the same file it creates a "duplicate" diagnostics issues list in the problems terminal window.

What is the best way to clear that terminal window problems? I have tried to run `collections.clear()` which I thought would do the job but it did not work.

Comment: The sample you linked only ever creates a single collection (which should be enough).

Comment: @Gama11 I do have a button that calls the command multiple times though and errors are stacking. Whats the way to clear those errors before running a new istance?

Comment: I don't see why you'd need to create a new instance just because the command is called multiple times. And yeah, `clear()` is how you clear it, are you sure you're calling it on the correct instance?

Comment: @Gama11 I think I might understand whats happening. If I re-run the command it creates a new istance and `collections.clear()` does not work. As a test I added a timeout of 15 secs and run that clear command in the same istance and the issues do go away...

Comment: Any tip on how to clear it everytime a new instance is run?

Comment: Just don't create a new instance, reuse the old one.